# java.lang.IllegalStateException Target host must not be null connecting to database

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, database

I am trying to connect to `localhost/myfile.php` on my computer. The PHP file converts database data into `JSON` which I want to parse after connecting. When I try to connect, I get

```
Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null,   
path=10.0.0.9/myfile.php
```

Any ideas?

```
public void getData(){
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("10.0.0.9/myfile.php");  
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr = entity.getContent();
}
catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        resultView.setText("Couldnt connect to database" + e);
```

Comment: Is that Target error coming from the client Java or the php program on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the URI scheme.

Try with `new HttpPost("http://10.0.0.9/myfile.php");`

Comment: @user2976670 Are you sure the exception is the same? "Target host must not be null connecting to database" occurs precisely when the scheme is missing.

Comment: It DID solve the exception, although it still isn't working right. But you were right, thanks

Comment: @user2976670 That's good to hear. Please be so kind as to accept the answer then ;)